# MySQL: Return two sets of results based on different dates in one query

Tags: mysql

I have the following queries:

```
SELECT SUM(`dollars`) FROM daily_stats WHERE `day` BETWEEN '2018-07-03' AND '2018-07-08'

SELECT SUM(`dollars`) FROM daily_stats WHERE `day` BETWEEN '2018-07-09' AND '2018-07-14'
```

I want to return the two sets of results in one query, preferably as columns with descriptive names.
Here is my attempt, but it doesn't work as expected, I get a syntax error (Error code 1064):

```
SELECT
 (SELECT SUM(`dollars`) FROM daily_stats WHERE `day` BETWEEN '2018-07-03' AND '2018-07-08') AS last_result,
 (SELECT SUM(`dollars`) FROM daily_stats WHERE `day` BETWEEN '2018-07-09' AND '2018-07-14') AS current_result,
FROM daily_stats
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Use case statement for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a conditional sum:

```
SELECT SUM(case when day BETWEEN '2018-07-03' AND '2018-07-08' then dollars else 0 end) w1,
       SUM(case when day BETWEEN '2018-07-09' AND '2018-07-14' then dollars else 0 end) w2
FROM daily_stats
```

This sums the `dollars` column only if the `case` is true.

Comment: Awesome it works, can you please explain this a bit better though?
Then I'll mark this as the answer...

Comment: @spongeworthy explain what? It seems somewhat self-explanatory!?!

Comment: @Strawberry Before I requested an explanation, juergen posted only a code snippet with no text whatsoever. Since I have no problem admitting I know very little about MySQL and as you can see, I **have** attempted to solve this myself with minimum knowledge, I needed a brief textual explanation of the conditional sum, which now I know is even possible.